# NetBeans not recognising syntax errors

Tags: java, netbeans, syntax, compiler-errors, ide

I've been using NetBeans IDE 8.0.1 for sometime now, midway of a project the IDE stopped recognising any syntax errors. Upgrading to NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 still makes no difference.

[image: enter image description]

The class file I was working on shows a error icon (on top of the page and also in the project directory) but no indication in the class on which line the error is, if any.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to add some screenshots showing the problem.  Have you tried removing and reinstalling NetBeans?

Comment: Hi Jim Garrison I uninstalled 8.0.1 and installed 8.0.2, don't have access yet to post screenshots here!

Comment: Hi @Jim Garrison I have added a screenshot describing the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found out that my code had some syntax errors that cause NB not to highlight any syntax error anymore. To fix it, it is relatively simple: compile your class to identify the syntax errors, fix them and you're back to normal.